# Text grammar with plural-singular

Tags: c#, grammar

I have a C# application that creates detailed text messages based upon various conditions that are encountered.  If there is more than one occurrence I must use the plural form of many of the words in the message and make sure all related parts of speech correspond correctly.  Such is the hazard of any language, but I was wondering if there is a good way to handle this.  Below is a very simplified example, where the first set is for just one occurrence and the second is for more than one:

```
        "The letter corresponds properly.\n" +
        "It must be capitalized.\n";

        "The letters correspond properly.\n" +
        "They must be capitalized.\n";
```

Currently I do something like the following, which is a real pain and kluge:

```
     string plural_s = plural ? "s" : "";
     string plural_s_negate = plural ? "" : "s";
     string plural_they = plural ? "They" : "It";

     "The letter" + plural_s + " correspond" + plural_s_negate + " properly.\n" +
        plural_they + " must be capitalized.\n";
```

In this simplified case it would obviously be better to just keep both literal cases and choose between them, but in many instances my explanations are quite long with many common parts, so I don't want to maintain two separate sets.

Answer (score 2):

[Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) does something like this, but it might be overkill for your needs, and at the same time won't help you with verbs.

If you know exactly what words you're going to manipulate, you can simplify your syntax by using a dictionary and an extension method:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static class PluralizeExtensions {
    private static Dictionary<string, string> pluralForms = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "letter", "letters" },
        { "corresponds", "correspond" },
        { "It", "They" }
    };

    public static string Pluralize(this string text, bool isPlural) {
        if (!isPlural) return text;
        var words = Regex.Split(text, @"\b");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
            if (pluralForms.ContainsKey(words[i])) words[i] = pluralForms[words[i]];
        }
        return string.Join("", words);
    }
}
```

You would use like this:

```
bool plural = WhateverYouDoToDecideIfItsPlural();

var text = ("The letter corresponds properly.\n" +
            "It must be capitalized.\n").Pluralize(plural);
```

Note that you could expand this method to better handle capitalization, if you need that flexibility.